# Drupal White Screen only on product page?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules, drupal-views, drupal-theming

I am pulling my hair out at this question. I have found many things of white screen of death and have tried many methods. Only my product page appears as a white background. However, links are still shown. I have tried clearing cache which didnt work as well as adding code to php and even looking a error logs which I understand none of. They all start with HTTP. But I dont think thats my problem. The theme I am using is aqua prospa . Plus I find it odd the this is only shown on my product page? Is there any way to fix this? Any suggestions would be grateful thank you!!

Comment: What do you get exactly ? A completely white screen (http://drupal.org/node/158043) or page with no CSS and messed up display ?

Comment: When developing in Drupal, or any LAMP app, understanding the error logs is a fundamental requirement you'll have to come to terms with. Also, you don't mention what non-core modules your site uses. Ubercart?